# hot vs cold observables when providing dedicated api access to be used by Angular components

Tags: angular, rxjs

While the general idea of hot and cold Observables seems quite clear to me I got confused when working on some specific case.

There is a feature flag API with client lib providing internal caching and exposing callback based access. I want to use that client in Angular by creating a service providing feature-flag Observables. As I need some extra configuration of the client and ensure on-demand refresh I came up with following way of creating the Observable:

```js
public flag$(key: string) {
    if (this.flagCache[key]) {
      return this.flagCache[key];
    }

    const observableKeyFlag$ = this.commonConfig$.pipe(
        map(config =>
            this.observableFlag$(key, config)),
        // shareReplay should ensure reuse of observableFlag$
        // creation on subsequent re/connects
        shareReplay({refCount: true, bufferSize: 1}),
        switchMap(cachedObservableFlag$ =>
            this.refresh$.pipe(
                filter(refreshKey => refreshKey === key),
                switchMap(() =>
                  cachedObservableFlag$))
    );

    return this.flagCache[key];
}

public refresh(key: string) {
  this.refresh$.next(key);
}
```

Now the key question is whether it's ok to return the observable as above (i.e thanks to the `shareReply()` OR to do

```js
  this.flagCache[key] = new ReplySubject(1);
  observableKeyFlag$.subscribe(this.flagCache[key]);  
  this.flagCache[key];
```

- what may be the difference between those two options?
- does the `shareReplay()` make an important difference in compare to `ReplySubject`?

NOTE: the `refresh$` part is a bit more complex keeping a map of keys for a component to refresh them all at once.

Don't think the matter of using the above in Angular changes anything but just for illustration the intended use is:

```html
<my-component>
   <some-section *ngIf="flag$('feature1')">
     Feature 1 content enabled
   </some-section>
   <some-section *ngIf="flag$('feature2')">
     Feature 2 content enabled
   </some-section>
</my-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked several questions.

So, I will try to answer some of them

yes it's okay to return the observable.

I try to always return an observable. This way, if I return an observable I can use a the async pipe, by using the async pipe I don't have to worry about subscribing and unsubscribing on ngOnDestroy.

Now, both of them are okay scenarios, but now it comes to you to the readability of your code and your code style/preference